# Are there more modern schools that follow Epicurean philosophy?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, pain-and-pleasure, epicurus

As Wikipedia says in its [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicureanism), Epicureanism in short means:

> pleasure is the highest good, thus gain it through living virtuous life and expecting less.

Based on this definition, is there a modern society, tribe, social network, or any group of people which can be considered Epicureanist?

Comment: Sort of nonsensical to ask if it "still exists": of course it does. The idea is still around, you just got finished reading an article about it. It *seems* that what you're asking is whether Epicureanism is still popular among contemporary philosophers, and whether it's used to justify any modern philosophical positions. I've tried to update the question to that end; please feel free to expand on my edits as you feel is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, I am not really familiar with the matter, although I had already encountered similar discussions. I would say that certain interpretations of religion suggest something similar to what you pointed out, and I have read several books containing a similar messages. Whether an entire society based on such concept exists, I would say no. Not because of the concept itself, but simply because finding one society in which every single member has the exact same view of the world is seemingly impossible, it would basically mean a group of clones. Even within the most strict assemblies, members still have maintain certain degree of divergence on their views, whether or not they are aware of it, this is a different story.